# Easy way to pass primitive value to ApiController using AutoFac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

Given the following method of configuring Autofac:

```
public class DefaultConfigurationModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

And given the following Web-Api controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly int _someValue;

    public MyController(int someValue)
    {
        _someValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

What would be the easiest way to pass `someValue` to `MyController`'s constructor?

I could create a `MyControllerConfig` class and register it with AutoFac:

```
public interface IMyControllerConfig
{
    int SomeValue { get; }
}

public class MyControllerConfig : IMyControllerConfig
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }

    public MyControllerConfig(int someValue)
    {
        SomeValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

And add it to my configurationmodule:

```
builder.Register(c => new MyControllerConfig(123)).As<IMyControllerConfig>();
```

And change `MyApiController` to accept an `IMyControllerConfig` instead of an `int`:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly int _someValue;

    public MyController(IMyControllerConfig myControllerConfig)
    {
        _someValue = myControllerConfig.SomeValue;
    }
}
```

The `IMyControllerConfig` interface may be overkill; I could've done without and just used the `MyControllerConfig`. But either way; this entire `MyControllerConfig` class seems overkill to pass a single (primitive) value into my ApiController. **Surely there's an easier, cleaner, neater way?**

If this weren't an ApiController I'd simply do:

```
builder.Register(c => new MyClass(123)).As<IMyInterface>();
```

...and just pass the integer in. But since it's a WebApi controller and I want to / like to use the `RegisterApiControllers` method (because there are lots of controllers that can be / are registered with this method just fine) I seem to paint myself into a corner. And changing `MyController` so it doesn't get '[picked up](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/blob/6a39cc99231f225d56b8294aa6b783cd55e5888d/src/Autofac.Integration.WebApi/RegistrationExtensions.cs#L71)' by the `RegisterApiControllers` method (i.e. by changing it's name to not end on 'Controller' for example) and registering this controller 'manually' <s>feels</s> *is* kind of 'dirty' too.

An alternative would be to implement a dependencyresolver and do the magic there, but again, this seems like a lot of work to pass a single primitive to a constructor. I understand, and agree, that using the above method (using a `MyControllerConfig` class) is better suited for future enhancement and passing more values without too much hassle but I don't need it for this particular project. All other API controllers in the project use either parameterless constructors or constructors that have interfaces for arguments.

<sub><sup>Note that the `123` "const" in above examples actually comes from a configurationfile and is only used for brevity in the above; if it were a constant I wouldn't need the constructor argument and could just put it in the `MyController` class directly.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the value is primitive and it comes from config the recommended solution is, in fact, to use a provider sort of interface. There are a lot of problems with having primitive constructor parameters (string, int, etc.), one of the main ones being that they're so primitive you can't [from a type perspective] differentiate what the purpose of each one actually is. Register a string in the container for one class that needs a connection string, some other class may inadvertently get it for some unrelated purpose.

The examples you describe [are actually right out of our FAQ on this topic](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-configured-parameters.html). If you can't/won't use the lambda, which *is that easier/neater/cleaner way you're looking for*, then a provider interface is the next best option.

Note you don't have to change your controller if you want to use the lambda.

```
// Register everything nicely
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
// Override just the one controller
builder.Register(ctx => new MyController(123)).As<MyController>();
```

Last in wins, so when Web API tries to resolve `MyController` it'll get the registration from the lambda.

Comment: `Last in wins` Isn't that relying on an implementation detail that may change at any time? Edit: turns out it's [documented](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations)....

Comment: Correct. This is the intended behavior of Autofac (and most other IoC containers).